# Which gold were they referring to in Matthew 23:16?

Tags: matthew, referent-identification, law, temple

Matthew 23:16 NIV

16 “Woe to you, blind guides! You say, ‘If anyone swears by the temple, it means nothing; but anyone ***who swears by the gold of the temple is bound by that oath***.

Could the blind guides have been referring to the golden vessels in the temple or the gold offered by the congregation

Which  gold were they referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Jerusalem's temple, in the time of Christ, was a wonderful building to behold. It was elevated, spectacular from the outside and full of gold items within. Note how Jesus gave that address while in the temple, and then went immediately out

> "...and departed from the temple: and his disciples came to him for to
> shew him the buildings of the temple. And Jesus said unto them, see ye
> not all these things? Verily I say unto you, There shall not be left
> here one stone upon another, that shall not be thrown down." Matthew
> 24:1-2 A.V.

The building was full of gold. Although people could put monetary offerings of gold into the temple coffers, coins of meager denomination and little worth were also accepted (as with the widow giving her last mite.) However, gold is gold is gold - irrespective of whether it covers parts of the temple, or its vessels which are made of gold, or it is gold coins given by worshippers when they come in. ***The emphasis Jesus gives is not about that which can be seen, but the false and unwarrantable distinctions some people were making with regard to swearing oaths to God.*** Jesus was warning about the danger of making light of any oaths being made to God. This commentator says:

> "[1.]  They allowed swearing by creatures, provided they were
> consecrated to the service of God, and stood in any special relation
> to him. They allowed swearing by the temple and the altar, though they
> were the work of men's hands, intended to be the servants of God's
> honour, not sharers in it. An oath is an appeal to God, to his
> omniscience and justice; and to make this appeal to any creature is to
> put that creature in the place of God. See Deut. 6:13.
>
> [2.]  They distinguished between an oath in *the temple* and an oath
> by *the gold of the temple;* an oath by *the altar* and an oath by
> *the gift gift upon the altar,* making the latter binding, but not the former. Here was a double wickedness. *First,* That there were some
> oaths which they dispensed with, and made light of, and reckoned a man
> was not bound by to assert the truth, or perform a promise. They ought
> not to have sworn by the temple or the altar, but when they had so
> sworn, they were taken in the words of their mouth. That doctrine
> cannot be of God of truth which gives countenance to the breach of
> faith in any case whatsoever. Oaths are edge-tools and are not to be
> jested with. *Secondly,* That they preferred the gold before the
> temple, and the gift before the altar, to encourage people to bring
> gifts to the altar, and gold to the treasures of the temple, which
> they hoped to be gainers by. Those who had made gold their hope, and
> whose eyes were blinded by gifts in secret, were great friends to the
> Corban;" *Commentary on the whole Bible*, Matthew Henry, p. 1379
> middle column, Hendrickson.

Corban was spoken of by Jesus in Mark 7:9-13 in connection with an oath taken by a mature son, telling his parents he would give much money to the temple, then the religious leaders telling him that his monetary gift would absolve him from looking after his parents. Jesus condemned that. It provides a good example of what Jesus was saying here in Matthew 23.

> "They that sware by the gold of the temple had an eye to it as holy;
> but what was it that made it holy but the holiness of the temple, to
> the service of which it was appropriated? And therefore the temple
> cannot be less holy than the gold, but must be more so, for the less
> is blessed and sanctified of the better. Heb.7:7 (*Ibid.* third
> column)

So, this commentator brings in both the gold within the temple, and the gold brought into the temple by the ones making oaths, to show that it is not the gold but the oaths that comprise the whole point of what Jesus was saying. It is not what those "blind guides" were referring to, but what Jesus was referring to that is the point of this text. The "blind guides" were fixated on the gold coming into the treasury; those giving gold to the treasury may have been fixated on the golden glitter of the temple - one group was no better than the other. Both were abusing the solemn, holy matter of making oaths before God because they attached more worth to gold than to God.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the question is: we are not told.  However, it is possible to make some reasonable estimates of what was intended.  Ellicott suggests:

> (16) Whosoever shall swear by the temple.—On the general teaching of
> the Pharisees as to oaths, see Notes on Matthew 5:33-37. It is not
> easy to trace the currents of thought that run through a corrupt
> casuistry, but probably the line of reasoning that led to this
> distinction was that the “gold of the Temple”—not the gold used in its
> structural ornamentation, but that which in coin or bullion was part
> of the Corban, or sacred treasure (Matthew 15:5)—had received a more
> special consecration than the fabric, and involved, therefore, a
> higher obligation, when used as a formula jurandi, than the Temple or
> the altar.

Similar Benson opines:

> But whosoever shall swear by the gold of the temple — That is, by the
> treasure kept there, he is a debtor — Gr. οφειλει, he oweth, that is,
> is obliged to perform his oath. “It seems,” says Dr. Doddridge, “the
> Pharisees taught, that oaths by the creatures might be used on
> trifling occasions, and violated without any great guilt. But they
> excepted oaths by the corban, (the gift,) and by sacrifices; in which
> it is plain that, without any regard to common sense or decency, they
> were influenced merely by a view to their own interest; and therefore
> represented these to the people as things of more eminent sanctity
> than even the temple or altar itself.”

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary reaches the same conclusion:

> but whosoever shall swear by the gold of the temple—meaning not the
> gold that adorned the temple itself, but the Corban, set apart for
> sacred uses (see on [1348]Mt 15:5).
>
> he is a debtor!—that is, it is no longer his own, even though the
> necessities of the parent might require it. We know who the successors
> of these men are.

Bengel and Pulpit commentary reach the same conclusion - the gold associated with the Corban excuse (gold gifts) by which the temple official enriched themselves.

Answer (score 0):

> Matthew 23:16 “Woe to you, blind guides! You say, ‘If anyone swears by the **temple**, it means nothing; but anyone who swears by the **gold** of the temple is bound by that oath.’ 17You blind fools! Which is greater: the gold, or the **temple that makes the gold sacred**?

If you consider the context, there are actually two meanings for the word "gold" here, one meant by the Pharisees et al and one meant by Jesus. The Pharisees was talking about the Corban treasury gold while Jesus was talking about the golden vessels in the temple, the candlestick and the gold with which the doors and other parts of the temple were covered, etc. Jesus' point was not to focus on the Corban gold, or even the adornment gold, but on the temple itself which is most important.

Answer (score 0):

Just as with the gold on the temple, these hypocrites put more emphasis on the material gift than the spiritual altar that sanctified the gift. Jesus revealed that the motives behind the gift are more important than the gift itself (Luke 21:1-4 and 1 Corinthians 13:3). An inferior material gift given with the proper motives is recognized by God as superior to a larger material gift given with the wrong motives.

Rather, this verse is all about ‘oaths’ - in particular the *basis* of, or what was used to ‘bind’ the oath. In this case, the *difference* between using the ‘temple’ - a spiritual value that they *didn’t* understand, therefore because they had no understanding of this, i.e. therefore this would have meant nothing, so this made it worthless as a ‘anchor’ for the oath.

Where as they *did* understand gold - a material value - therefore this made or would have given the ‘oath’ a meaningful foundation.

In the Hebrew way of thinking, an oath was a solemn appeal to the truth of an affirmation or promise. The Law of Moses established guidance concerning oaths in several situations: the loss of one’s personal property (Exodus 22:10-11), the finding of lost possessions (Leviticus 6:3), when a woman was suspected of unfaithfulness to her husband (Numbers 5:11-31), and the misuse of swearing and concealing the truth (Leviticus 5:1). All of these were ‘real’ (non spiritual)

The Old Testament also cautioned against swearing lightly with the solemn warning of Ecclesiastes 5:5, “Better is it that thou shouldest not vow, than that thou shouldest vow and not pay.” Gold therefore having ‘real’ value, it’s ‘loss’ would have an impact - makes the ‘oath’ valid.

Where as the temple would have had no such ‘bind’ on the oath.